# What's a good way (using CSS) to extend part of an element on click?

Tags: html, css

I've attached two images showing the effect I'm trying to achieve, and what's wrong with the way I'm currently doing it. The first is displayed on page load, the second when you click on the down arrow.

The second partially obscures the first, currently using a negative margin. My current version has an invisible element underneath the leftmost box containing the icon, which has the same class as it that handles indentation. But At certain screen widths you get the effect below, where you can see the expanded section's border running halfway up the original element.

I've tried a few things to get rid of the glitch, but it's feeling a lot like pressing down bubbles - either they create worse problems, or the same problem at different widths.

I have the strong suspicion that I'm doing this all wrong, but I haven't thought of a better way to generate the same effects - border around the whole thing, text from the expanded element getting pulled up to approx where the original summary text was.

I can afford to use fairly modern CSS for this - our audience tends to be pretty high tech. In case relevant, I'm using a transition animation for the height increase, so it needs to be something consistent with that.

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix for your problem is to make the left icon area overlap the rest (using `z-index` and `position:relative`) and extending it by `1px` (so it covers the border in all cases).

Update your question with a code example and I'll update my answer with the fix, if the principle outlined above is not enough.

---

The alternative is to empirically determine the widths at which the border is misplaced and adjust the width of your dropdown, using `@media` queries.

Another rather important aspect which you don't seem to have determined is if the bug is specific to any particular browsers/devices.

As a side-note, I find quite a few questions similar to yours have one (rather silly) common cause: the developer has unknowingly changed the zoom level of their browser, pressing either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, viewing the page at `90%` or `110%`. Make sure you're developing at a zoom level of `100%`, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.

I'd also like to suggest you take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get tips on improving your question(s), to increase your chances of getting better answers.